# Why when I use RegularExpression as DataAnnotation is not recognizing the leading zeros?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex, validation

I have a field in my entity which have a RegularExpression as a DataAnnotation:

```
@"^\$?([0-9]{6})(.[0-9]){0,1}?$"
```

And it always works fine, except when I use zeros before the number.

Ex.

```
- 123456.1    Work
- 012345.1    Does Not Work
```

If I do the same validation with Regex.IsMatch it says is ok.

How can I force MVC to Keep the leading zeroes when it does the validation?

Comment: @hwnd it is supposed to let you write one digit after the decimal point, or nothing at all. If I remove the anchors I cannot do this last part.

Comment: @hwnd I did not write it down, cuz that was working fine. I have just updated the example.

Comment: @hwnd The only reason why I have it in a separated  group is because I wanted to specify that there can be one ocurrence  or there can be none.

Comment: I don't think this is your issue, but you should escape the period in your second group if you want it to only match a literal `.` character. Otherwise it'll match "123456Q1", "123456@1", etc.

Comment: `{0,1}` followed by `?` is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used a string variable and this was what worked:

> ^\$?([0-9]{6})(\.[0-9])?$

- I followed @Sinsedrix and @Michelle advice